# Julia PythonCall.jl how do I handle Python exceptions?

Tags: julia, pythoncall.jl

Using [PythonCall.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PythonCall.jl) and its [Docs](https://juliapy.github.io/PythonCall.jl/stable/pythoncall-reference/), how do I best handle python exception patters such as the following python:

```
try:
  database = client.create_database(DATABASE_NAME)
except exceptions.CosmosResourceExistsError:
  database = client.get_database_client(DATABASE_NAME)
```

Comment: *How \*can\* I handle them?* is a fairly objective question, whereas *how do I \*best\* handle them?* is fairly subjective. Consider rephrasing your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer was provided on how to best handle python exceptions using pythoncall.jl

https://github.com/JuliaPy/PythonCall.jl/issues/388

The answer from the above link is as follows:

This in Julia

```
julia> try
           @pyexec "raise ValueError('foo')"
       catch err
           if err isa PyException && pyisinstance(err, pybuiltins.ValueError)
               @info "handling a ValueError"
           else
               rethrow()
           end
       end
[ Info: handling a ValueError
```

is roughly equivalent to this in Python

```
>>> try:
...     raise ValueError('foo')
... except ValueError as err:
...     print('handling a ValueError')
...
handling a ValueError
```

Comment: That answer doesn't seem like it's mainly subjective: "Python exceptions get thrown in Julia as `PyException`" is pretty useful information. You can add the content of their reply to this post, and accept this as the answer.